# Python: POSIX character class in regex?

Tags: python, regex, character-class

How can I search for, say, a sequence of 10 `isprint` characters in a given string in Python?

With GNU grep, I would simply do `grep [[:print:]]{10}`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since POSIX is not supported by Python `re` module, you have to emulate it with the help of character class.

You can use the one from the [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) and add a limiting quantifier `{10}`:

```
[\x20-\x7E]{10}
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oE4cC7/1)

Alternatively, you can use [Matthew Barnett regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) that claims to support POSIX character classes (*POSIX character classes are supported.*).

Comment: This character class worked for me in Python 3 `[\`~!@#$%^&*()_=+\[\]{}\\\|;:\"\'<>.,/?]` when using inside the `re.sub()` method

Comment: @Iota, that ``[`~!@#$%^&*()_=+\[\]{}\\\|;:\"\'<>.,/?]`` only matches ASCII punctuation, it has nothing to do with the concept of "printable chars". So, if you were to use a POSIX character class, it would be `[[:punct:]]`. To match punctuation in Python, you can use `[^\w\s]`, although there are better and more precise patterns.

Comment: My mistake! I misread the `[[:print]]` class as `[[:punct]]`. Appreciate your correction.

Comment: The regex in the answer will not match Unicode non-ASCII characters like grep (GNU grep) does.

Comment: @pabouk-Ukrainestaystrong Then see the bottom of the answer. Just install the PyPi regex module (`pip install regex` in the console/terminal) and then use `import regex` and `pattern = regex.compile(r'[[:print:]]{10}')`.