# Regular expression error: unbalanced parenthesis at position n

Tags: python, regex

I have been meaning to extract the month name from the following string with regex and despite the fact that my regex works on a platform like regex101, I can't seem to be able to extract the word "August".

```
import re
s = "word\anyword\2021\August\202108_filename.csv"
re.findall("\d+\\([[:alpha:]]+)\\\d+", s)
```

Which results in the following error:

> error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 17

I also tried using `re.compile`, `re.escape` as per suggestions of the previous posts dealing with the same error but none of them seems to work.

Any help and also a little explanation on why this isn't working is greatly appreciated.

Comment: To be clear, `s` also isn't what you expect. If you `print(repr(s))`, you get `'word\x07nyword\x821\\August\x82108_filename.csv'` because `\a` represents a [BELL character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character), and `\2021` is interpreted as octal. There's an existing question: [Windows path in Python](/q/2953834/4518341)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
s = r"word\anyword\2021\August\202108_filename.csv"
m = re.search(r"\d+\\([a-zA-Z]+)\\\d+", s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/hCC9MK).

There are three main problems here:

- The input string should be the same as used at regex101.com, i.e. you need to make sure you are using literal backslashes in the Python code, hence the use of raw string literals for both the input text and regex
- The POSIX character classes are [not supported by Python `re`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31915488/3832970), so `[[:alpha:]]+` should be replaced with some equivalent pattern, say, `[A-Za-z]+` or `[^\W\d_]+`
- Since it seems like you only expect a single match (there is only one `August` (month) name in the string), you do not need `re.findall`, you can use `re.search`. Only use `re.findall` when you need to extract multiple matches from a string.

Also, see these posts:

- [Python regex - r prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2241600/3832970)
- [What does the "r" in pythons re.compile(r' pattern flags') mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21104476/3832970)
- [What exactly do "u" and "r" string flags do, and what are raw string literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2081640/3832970)